# Oracle APEX load more than 45 columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.3 and tried to create a Data Load Wizard where a user submits a CSV with 67 columns but ran into the problem where there is a 45 column limit for the Data Load Wizard. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, APEX 5.1.3 has this limit. There are however work arounds using external table or loading the table and writing your own post-process.

[Import  data in excel to database table](https://community.oracle.com/message/9316828#9316828)

[Upload data from csv to table in APEX](https://community.oracle.com/message/2345886#2345886)

Comment: Hi Chaitanya - I followed the "Import data in excel to database table" link and recreated his process but am getting the following error:

ORA-06550: line 29, column 15: PLS-00201: identifier 'HEX_TO_DECIMAL' must be declared ORA-06550: line 29, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I can post the PL/SQL process here if you'd like with more space, any idea why i'm getting that?

Comment: See the hex_to_decimal function: http://www.orafaq.com/node/895